# Show that the positive solution of $a = \tanh(ax)$ satisfies $\frac{1}{1-a^2} > x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $x>1$ and $a = \tanh(ax)$ be positive (out of the three roots).

How can I conclude that
$$
\frac{1}{1-a^2} > x?
$$

---

**Context of how this popped up:**

I was solving the Ising model in the mean field theory for zero magnetic field case. But all this can be ignored if one is not familiar. The following is the relevant math.

I had to *minimize* $F(M)$, and it turned out that
\begin{align}
F'(M) &= -(NqJ)M + \frac{N}{2\beta}\ln\left( \frac{1+M}{1-M} \right)\quad\text{and,}\\
F''(M) &= \frac{N}{\beta}\left( -\beta qJ + \frac{1}{1-M^2} \right),
\end{align}
where $\beta$, $N$, $q$, $J$ are constants of the theory. $M$ is the variable.

It is easily seen that $F'(M) = 0$ corresponds to the transcendental equation $M = \tanh(\beta qJM)$, which splits into two cases:

1. $\beta qJ \le 1$.
   Then we have the only solution to be $M = 0$, which also happens to be a minimum.
2. $\beta qJ> 1$.
   Then we have three solutions to the transcendental equation, say $-M_s, 0, M_s$ (with $M_s > 0$). Then $M = 0$ is *not* a minimum. To show that $M_s$ (and hence $-M_s$) is a local minimum, I needed the inequality to hold.

Comment: @MartinR The context is highly nonmathematical. Hence I did not include it. It comes when I was analyzing the Ising model in the mean field theory in the case, and confirming the nonzero magnetization in the region $T<T_C$. I think that's confusing enough.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I'll try to add more relevant parts.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the inverse hyperbolic tangent as an integral and estimate the derivate:
$$
ax = \operatorname{arctanh} (a) = \int_0^a \frac{dt}{1-t^2} < \frac{a}{1-a^2} \, ,
$$
which implies that $x < \frac{1}{1-a^2}$.

Or, using the mean-value theorem:
$$
 x = \frac 1a \operatorname{arctanh} (a) = \frac{\operatorname{arctanh} (a)-\operatorname{arctanh} (0)}{a-0} = \frac{1}{1-t^2} < \frac{1}{1-a^2}
$$
for some $t \in (0, a)$.

Comment: How did you ensure that $a<1$?

Comment: @Atom: $a = \tanh(ax)$ implies $|a| < 1$.